# SDelete: where to get the physical disk number from?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space, secure-erase, wipe

Until recently, I have deleted hard disks this way:

1. Delete all partitions in Windows
2. Create a single partition for the whole drive
3. Assign a drive letter
4. Run `sdelete -z` with the drive letter

New versions of [SysInternals SDelete](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/sdelete.aspx) can wipe disks by their disk number. This means to me that I could skip steps 1, 2 and 3, which would be nice.

However, I'm uncertain what "physical disk number" is. Is it identical to the numbers I see in Windows disk management? That number seems to be consistent with the information I get from `list disk` in `diskpart`, so it might be a good choice.

If not, where do I get it from? I don't want to accidentally delete the wrong drive.

Note that the website doesn't even tell us about this option at the moment, so here's where I got that physical disk number info from:

```
SDelete v2.0 - Secure file delete
Copyright (C) 1999-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

usage: sdelete [-p passes] [-r] [-s] [-q] <file or directory> [...]
       sdelete [-p passes] [-z|-c [percent free]] <drive letter [...]>
       sdelete [-p passes] [-z|-c] <physical disk number>                            <---
   -c         Clean free space. Specify an option amount of space
              to leave free for use by a running system.
   -p         Specifies number of overwrite passes (default is 1)
   -r         Remove Read-Only attribute
   -s         Recurse subdirectories
   -z         Zero free space (good for virtual disk optimization)
   -nobanner  Do not display the startup banner and copyright message.

Disks must not have any volumes in order to be cleaned.
```

Comment: Perhaps to see with "Diskpart", it shows also useful informations about the disks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I read the text the console output more thoroughly, I saw the sentence

```
Disks must not have any volumes in order to be cleaned.
```

So I can't get rid of step 1 in my list, but that adds a lot of safety: it's not so simple to accidentally delete the wrong disk. So I just went on and tried what I have already expected and deleted the disk by its number in Disk Management.

Conclusion: yes, it's the number that's listed in Disk Management after the word "Disk". That's the same number as written by the command `list disk` in the `diskpart` tool.

Comment: Note that *"cleaning"* (`-c`) is different from *"zeroing"* (`-z`).

Comment: Great question and answer, thank you! Another way to find the disk number is in Disk Management: In Explorer right click on My Computer -> Manage -> Storage/Disk management. It lists disks with numbers in the bottom part of the screen.